# N:N Relation Mysql

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem in many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792883/problem-in-many-to-many-relationship)

I have a table of movies and a table of categories. I would like to register one more category for a film. And a category for several films. That is, a relation N: N. How do I do that in php and Mysql?

For example: 
Categorie 1 -> Movie 1
           and Movie 2

Movie 2 -> Categorie 1
        and Categorie 2

Comment: You create a table in between called `movie_categories`, storing the relationship between each `movie` and `category`.

Comment: Did you try the search function on SO, there are more than many questions about many to many relationships!

Answer (score 3):

For a [many to many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29), you need a third table called the [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

So it would look like that

```
Movie
id | desc

Category
id | desc

MoviesCategories
id | movieID | categoryId
```

Your selects would be on `MoviesCategories` and would look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 MoviesCategories INNER JOIN Category ON MoviesCategories.CategoryId = Category.Id 
                  INNER JOIN movie ON MoviesCategories.MovieID = Movie.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response and devote your precious time to help me.

Comment: @ThainãMonteiro Glad to help :) Don't forget to mark the answer that helped you. You can check the white check beside the answer

Answer (score 2):

You need a table for that relationship.  Like this:

```
MovieToCategory
    ID
    CategoryID
    MovieID
```

Alternatively you can create a composite primary index only allowing each movie to category combination one time:

```
MovieToCategory
    CategoryID
    MovieID
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response and devote your precious time to help me.