# MySQL many to mny (n:n): Setting 1 entry as main entry

Tags: mysql, sql

Using this example[1](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/many-to-many.html) for a n:n relationship:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tekstenuitleg.net](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/static/images/beertable.gif))</sub>

What would be the best way to set a main or primary many-to-many field? Example: Let's say I want to set distributor "Devrolijke drinker" (ID AB999) as main or preferred distributor for "Sint" beer (ID 160). My first guess would be be to add an additional field in the junction table, e.g. `(bool) is_primary`. But this could easily become inconsistent if two fields would be (accidentally) set to `true`, right? Any ideas? Thanks!

**Reference**

[1 The many-to-many relationship](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/many-to-many.html)

[2 Another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792883/problem-in-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: preferred does not sound many to many to me. u gotta decide this

Comment: You can always set all the distributors to false (talking about the `is_primary` field) before setting the new primary one to true so it won't be inconsistent.

Comment: keep your intersect/junction for many to many. and in the beer table save the preferred distr

Comment: For the sake of consistence and easier query-coding, I tend to prefer Shomz's solution. Because: what if in one entry a distributor is listed in the junction-table **and** in the beer table again as preferred distributor. And then on the other side in another entry perhaps not? I think, it's easier to avoid duplicates with a `is_primary` field in the junction-table.

Comment: well how many primaries are ya gonna have for any 1 beer. answer: 0 or 1

Comment: Right. 0 or 1. Beer Foo will have a favorite distributor, but beer Bar will have none... But my main concern is to **easily** avoid inconsistence.

Comment: so Beer Foo has 19 distributors. and to clean up the mess of primary i have to do 'update beer_distributor set is_primary=false where beer_id=157' for 19 rows, followed up with  "update beer_distributor set is_primary=true where beer_id=157 and dist_id='CA938'". If that makes sense to you.

Comment: O.K. :-) If I would "just" have a field "primary_distributor_id" in my beer-table, I would still have to either (a) check if this distributor is also listed in the junction table or (b) check if it is **not** listed in the junction table.

(a) if i would do sth. like: `select * from junction-table where beer = foo` then: mark distributer, which is also listed in beer table (as preferred).

(b) `select distributor with id from primary_distributor-field from beers` then: `select all other distributors from junction-table` ...rather complicated... ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29791/discussion-between-mdthh-and-drew-pierce)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can adda "preferred distributer" column to the beer table, which will have the preferred distributor's ID as the datatype. then add another column of main distributor with that distributor ID.  This will allow for the queries n joins you want it sounds like.

2) You can use a numbering system. Add this as a single column to the "beer distributor" table. You can make main distributor = 1, preferred distributor = 2, etc.  Then query by this value if you want to find all preferred distributors of a beer.  (This way would work better if you have more than one preferred distributor for the same beer.